# How can images inside Boostrap Carousel have the same width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

This is actually a copy paste from the bootstrap website, I have also tried many other things, and to be honest I am struggling to understand how can these pictures have the same size. If you click next on the carousel you will see that the height is always different!

So how can I do it? I have tried to change the properties of the inner carousel, the div that I created, the different divs, but nothing happens. Especially when I use my own images the size is always weird.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="justAContainer">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5Ldsk48qcVYHL8b7hOl1kN1KMTQaE2oFlt34OkdrCELVLVZairaj4ros7uyKGQfhrTaQ&usqp=CAU" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRY8OmOh5BYsSROeZ2ZLdOD-s1IlDe9JyF08hRqKXZX_79JiXT00FAuM1lO0PS3roGwQiw&usqp=CAU" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#startingPageCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#startingPageCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class `w-100` in every image which is bootstrap default class for width: 100%. So it will automatically take full width. If you want the heights same, there are 2 ways for it. (1) You must update same width and height images or make the `background-image` and give the `div` `width:100%` and specify its height.

Thanks me later.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="justAContainer">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5Ldsk48qcVYHL8b7hOl1kN1KMTQaE2oFlt34OkdrCELVLVZairaj4ros7uyKGQfhrTaQ&usqp=CAU" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRY8OmOh5BYsSROeZ2ZLdOD-s1IlDe9JyF08hRqKXZX_79JiXT00FAuM1lO0PS3roGwQiw&usqp=CAU" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#startingPageCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#startingPageCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```